# How do I block pushing --upstream to remote master branch

Tags: git, github

I'm aware of the git config:

```
git config branch.master.pushRemote no_push
```

Which has saved me a number of time from accidentally pushing to master remote branch, but a couple of times this hasn't worked, and I couldn't understand why, until today, I realised that if I push but set upstream... Well it pushes to the origin, which isn't great.

`git push --set-upstream origin {git_current_branch}` <-- I have this as alias `gpsup` hence it's an easy mistake to make.

How can I disable pushing toe the remote branch even if I accidentally use the --set-upstream flag?

Comment: Since you tagged this `github` you could configure protected branches on github.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I disable pushing toe the remote branch even if I accidentally use the `--set-upstream` flag?

You need to configure the remote side.
On GitHub, as commented, that would be using a [branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches).
But other remote Git repository hosting services (Bitbucket,  GitLab, ...) have their own version of that too.

The point is: a git config solution is *local* to your workstation, and (as you have seen) might not be 100% reliable.
A remote-side solution is easier to setup and to enforce (not just from your workstation, but for everyone, from anywhere).